# How to add simple label on dialog.xml in CQ5 AEM?

Tags: adobe, aem, experience-manager

I have to design my CQ5 dialog as given in the following image. I have designed almost all the dialog but unable to add simple two labels side by side highlighted as red. Can someone please suggest how I can achieve it in dialog.xml ? 
[image]

Comment: Hello touseefkhan4pk,  Can you please help me with, How you have set the checkbox horizontally, will be help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **label** xtype from [CQ Widget API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.Label) with style property which you can use as follows:

```
<label_1
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    style="width: 50%;display: inline;margin-left: 100px;font-weight: 600;"
    text="Use as default filter"
    xtype="label"/>
<label_2
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    style="width: 50%;display: inline;margin-left: 40px;font-weight: 600;"
    text="Show Advanced Options"
    xtype="label"/>
```

You can change style according to your need.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for.